# OpenLDAP as Proxy

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, proxy, authentication, openldap, ubuntu-16.04

**First, please note that I have experience with Linux, but for some reason, the OpenLDAP proxy authentication has me very confused and so I'm hoping someone can simply answer my questions to help me better understand it.  I was following this tutorial to set up a proxy to a Active Directory authentication (https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/OpenLDAP_as_proxy_to_AD).**

Some notes:

- The OpenLDAP server's IP is 10.41.22.103
- The Windows AD server IP is 10.41.22.100
- OpenLDAP admin account is cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com

**Following the tutorial, here are the files I modified.**

**My slapd.conf file (/etc/ldap/slapd.conf):**

```
### Schema includes ####

include                 /etc/ldap/schema/core.schema
include                 /etc/ldap/schema/cosine.schema
include                 /etc/ldap/schema/inetorgperson.schema
include                 /etc/ldap/schema/misc.schema
include                 /etc/ldap/schema/nis.schema

## Module paths ##############################################################

modulepath              /usr/lib/ldap
moduleload              back_ldap
moduleload              rwm

# Main settings ###############################################################

pidfile                 /var/run/slapd/slapd.pid
argsfile                /var/run/slapd/slapd.args

### Database definition (Proxy to AD) #########################################

database                ldap
readonly                yes
protocol-version        3
rebind-as-user          yes
uri                     "ldap://10.41.22.100:389"
suffix                  "dc=OneGeo,dc=local"
overlay                 rwm
rwm-map                 attribute       uid     sAMAccountName
#rwm-map                 attribute       mail    proxyAddresses

### Logging ###################################################################

logfile                 /var/log/slapd/slapd.log
loglevel   0
```

**In my Server 2012 AD, I created a user as requested and this is its DN:**

```
CN=nslcd connect,CN=Users,DC=OneGeo,DC=local
```

**Here is what I put into the core.schema (/etc/ldap/schema/core.schema):**

```
####sAMAccountName AttributeType####

attributetype ( 1.2.840.113556.1.4.221
NAME 'sAMAccountName'
SYNTAX '1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15'
SINGLE-VALUE )
```

**Here is what I put into the nslcd.conf file (/etc/nslcd.conf):**

```
# Mappings for Active Directory

pagesize 1000
referrals off

# Passwd

filter passwd (&(objectClass=posixAccount)(!(objectClass=computer))(uidNumber=*))

map    passwd homeDirectory     UnixHomeDirectory
map    passwd gecos             displayName
map    passwd gidNumber         primaryGroupID


# Shadow

filter shadow (&(objectClass=posixAccount)(!(objectClass=computer))(uidNumber=*))
map    shadow shadowLastChange  pwdLastSet

##new
filter passwd (uid=*)

# Groups

#filter group (&(objectClass=posixGroup)(gidNumber=*))
filter group  (&(objectClass=group)(gidNumber=*))
#map    group gid       member

# Local account for nsclcd

uid nslcd
##gid ldap
gid nslcd

# Where is the LDAP

uri ldap://10.41.22.100:389
base dc=OneGeo,dc=local

# Connect-Account

binddn  CN=nslcd\connect,CN=Users,DC=OneGeo,DC=local
bindpw n3m3s1s
ssl no
```

**The last step in that tutorial mentions the pam_ldap.conf file, but I can't seem to find it on the OpenLDAP server.  Here are some questions I have (more will probably come):**

1. Where is the pam_ldap.conf file and should it be on the OpenLDAP server or on a client?
2. Once all of this is set up properly, how do I fully test it to ensure authentication is happening at the AD level?  I'm really confused about this part!

Thank you!

- Christian